# Confusion about How to populate xmlfile

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I  need to create a  xml file programmatically like below.

```
<Players> 
   <Player>
  <Name>C.Ronaldo</Name> 
 <Team>Man Utd</Team>
  <Position>Midfielder</Position>
  </Player> 
 </Players>
```

The problem is that the xml file which is created is not what I expect .How can fix this code 
Thanks in advance

```
      XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null));
        XElement root = new XElement("Players");
        xdoc.Add(root);
        XElement player = new XElement("Player");



        XElement[] el = {
                           new XElement("Name","xxx"),
                           new XElement("Team","dfdf"),
                           new XElement("Position","dsds")


                        };
        xdoc.Root.Add(el);

        xdoc.Save("myxml.xml", SaveOptions.None);
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest solution for your code would be to replace

```
xdoc.Root.Add(el);
```

with this:

```
player.Add(el);
xdoc.Root.Add(player);
```